# Binding to other element (Height minus 5px)

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, xaml, binding

Following code is okey.

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Class="Window1"
    x:Name="Window1" Title="Window1" 
    Height="200" Width="300">

<Grid>
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="False">
        <Rectangle DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="{Binding ElementName=Button1, Path=Height}"  Width="70" Fill="Yellow"></Rectangle>
        <Button x:Name="Button1" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Background="Red" Height="50" Width="70"/>
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Following code is need to be repaired.

```
<Rectangle DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="Button1.Height-5px"  Width="70" Fill="Yellow"></Rectangle>
```

Comment: You have a hardset Height on your Button1 to start with, why not just make the height of the Rect hardset at 45 to get your 50-5=45?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I not sure what you wanna obtain, but i you wanna get height - 5, just use binding with converter.

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:younamespace"
    x:Class="Window1"
    x:Name="Window1" Title="Window1" 
    Height="200" Width="300">
<Window.Resources>
<local:RactangleHeightConverters x:Key="NameConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>   
<Grid>
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="False">
         <Rectangle DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="{Binding ElementName=Button1, Path=Height,Converter={StaticResource NameConverter}}"  Width="70" Fill="Yellow"></Rectangle>
        <Button x:Name="Button1" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Background="Red" Height="50" Width="70"/>
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

More info
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/87b416/wpf-value-converters/

Make class with implements "IValueConverter"

```
using System;  

namespace ValueConverters  
{  
    class RactangleHeightConverters:IValueConverter  
    {  
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)  
        {  
            return value - 5;
        }  

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)  
        {  
           return null;
        }  
    }  
}
```

Comment: It works for me, but, in my case, because it's applied to a responsive grid, Path should be Path=ActualHeight instead of Height.

Answer (score 0):

A converter seems to be the only way. But in the specific instance of trying to bind a **ComboBox** width with its containing **GridViewColumn** width, in which case the drop down button might get hidden. A negative border margin can be applied to do the trick without using a converter.

[image: Drop down button]

```
<ListView x:Name="ListViewObjectMapping" Margin="0,0,0,-5">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn x:Name="GridViewColumnCategoryButtonHidden" Header="Category" Width="200">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox x:Name="ComboBoxButtonHidden" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Value.LinkedInstances}" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Value.LinkedInstance}" Width="{Binding Path=Width, Mode=OneWay, ElementName=GridViewColumnCategoryButtonHidden}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>    
            <GridViewColumn x:Name="GridViewColumnCategoryButtonVisible" Header="Category" Width="200">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border Margin="-6">
                            <ComboBox x:Name="ComboBoxButtonVisible" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Value.LinkedInstances}" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Value.LinkedInstance}" Width="{Binding Path=Width, Mode=OneWay, ElementName=GridViewColumnCategoryButtonVisible}"/>
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>    
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```